# Chatbot not visible in Microsoft Teams people list

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Previously, I had published my Chatbot using MS bot framework in Skype for Business.
However, later I realized that buttons, cards and carousels are not supported in the SFB.

So, I gave up troubleshooting on that and went on to publish the same bot to Microsoft Teams.

It deployed successfully and I am able to see the deployed chatbot in people's list when I open my MSTeams account. Besides that, I can also see the chatbot that was deployed in Skype for business.

However, none of my colleagues are able to view my published bot.

It only shows the old bot imported from SFB.

Is there some kind of access related configuration I need to do? If not, what else is missing here?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps to enable your bot on Teams channel?
1. Did your O365 tenant administrator enable sideloading(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/setup) of apps for your organization?
2. Did you create an app package (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/createpackage)
3. Did you sideload your bot app (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/sideload) into the relevant team?

Comment: I am new to  MSteams, what is meant by side-loading? I have not created an app package or did any kind of configuration from MSTeams side. All I did was create a bot using VS2017 , deploy in azure and select MSTeams channel while publishing. Is it mandatory to use an app package? Can we not use this bot like any other contact in MSteams?

Comment: We need to create package. [here] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) is the documentation to create manifest for your app.